# Trouble connecting database with ajax to php

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I'm having trouble connecting to database using Ajax, it didn't even run the .php file. I'd check under console this is the error

> GET http://local.testing.info/connections/getTag.php?q=a 404 (Not
>   Found)

Under Debug:

> xmlhttp = XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: ""…}

below are my code

**html:**

```
<div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.age" placeholder="Age">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{{data}}
```

**js**:

```
test.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    $scope.$watchCollection('person', function(newVal){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            $scope.data = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getTag.php?q="+newVal.name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
}
```

**php:**

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="123"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="testing"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$link)or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM testing.people WHERE name = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$name =$row['name'];

if($name == '' || empty($name)) {
  echo "<b>ID not found.</b>";
} else {
  echo "<b>".$name."</b>";
}

mysql_close($link);
```

Please advise where did I done wrong?

Comment: What is the specific error? Please add the php source code.

Comment: You are getting a 404, so most likely you simply specified the path wrong.

Comment: sql injection in 3, 2 ...

Comment: my **getTag.php** is at the same path as my script folder, i'd tried shifting to another folder called **connections**, and on javascript I specify `xmlhttp.open("GET","./connections/getTag.php?q="+newVal.name,true);` however the error still persist

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides its own http service for ajax.
try:

```
test.controller('formController',($scope,$http) {
   $scope.$watchCollection('person', function(newVal){
      var url = "YOUR_AJAX_PHP_URL";
      var req = {
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'http://example.com',
         data: { test: 'test' }
        }
      $http(req).then(function(response){/* success code here */}, function(response){/* fail code here */});
   });
});
```

reference: [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Edit: changed example as per request in the comments

Comment: Hi, thanks I knew about that, but this get function can't pass in value and return data, which is why I use ajax

Comment: Thanks, have read it, but do you know where I can find example on how to use it if I have optional config, and on php how do I retrieve that optional config value;

Comment: @nicker Changed the example with another one from the docs.. this one uses the $http() function directly.. P.S. You can access the data from PHP by using $_POST